# Python -Why cannot change the value in the C callback function?

Tags: python, ctypes

I try to using python ctype to call C library (.so) , and this C library have callback function.
C source code:

---

```
int showHelloword(int *result)
{
    *result = 1025;
    return 55;
}

void BSP_SHOW(int time,int (*callback)(int *result))
{
    int ret = 44;
    int boo = 4;
    while(time > 0){
        --time;
        if(time == 0){
            if(callback) {
                printf("boo %d\n",boo);      // I expect boo=4
                ret = callback(&boo);
                printf("Outfunc=%d\n",boo);  // I expect Outfunc=1025
                printf("ret=%d\n",ret);      // I expect ret=55
            }        
            callback = 0;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void main(){
    BSP_SHOW( 2, &showHelloword);
}
```

The print rseult is :

```
boo=4
Outfunc=1025
ret=55
```

And it seem okay.

Makefile source :

```
gcc -c -fPIC -Wno-format-security -g main.c
gcc -shared -o libcall.so main.o
gcc main.o -o callback -ldl -lpthread -lrt
```

---

THEN, I try to using python ctype to call "BSP_SHOW" this function and get callback into this function.
Python source :

Python version : 2.6.6

---

```
import sys
import os
import time
from ctypes import *
import struct
from Queue import *

class callback_api(object):

    def __init__(self):
        CDLL("/usr/lib64/librt.so",mode=RTLD_GLOBAL)
        path = "/root/workspace/callback/libcall.so"  `C library path`
        self.dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(path)

    def BSP_SHOW(self,sec, cb_func):
        self.dll.BSP_SHOW.restype = None
        self.dll.BSP_SHOW.argtypes = [c_int, qa_cb_prototype]
        self.dll.BSP_SHOW(c_int(sec),cb_func)


    def qa_callback(result):
        result = 1025 #it should change the value. but the result is not....
        return 88

qa_cb_prototype = CFUNCTYPE( c_int, POINTER(c_int))
qa_cache_cb_func = qa_cb_prototype(qa_callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = callback_api()
    api.BSP_SHOW(2,qa_cache_cb_func) `got it callback`
```

---

The print result is.

```
cb=4
Outfunc=4 <---I expect it should be 1025,but not! 
ret=88 <---return value have been change by python callback.
```

Have someone know is this a python ctype limitation or I use a wrong method?
Thanks!

Comment: Python version 2.6.6

Comment: Please help me! if someone know?!

Answer (score 0):

The = operator reassigns a variable in python. In other words, you change what the variable means.

You need to change what the variable is pointing to. Since it's a ctypes pointer, you need to index it with 0 to do this.

```
    def qa_callback(result):
        result[0] = 1025
        return 88
```

Note the `[0]` after result.

See also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#pointers